# Solve $ 11 \cdot 16^{1/(n-1)} = 16^{n/(n-1)} - 10 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is probably an easy task for the users here, but I could not solve it.

$$
11 \cdot 16^{1/(n-1)} = 16^{n/(n-1)} - 10
$$

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com) gives the result $ n= 5 $.

What are the steps to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$11\times 16^{\frac{1}{n-1}}=16^{1+\frac{1}{n-1}}-10=16\times 16^{\frac{1}{n-1}}-10$, so $5\times 16^{\frac{1}{n-1}}=10$, so $16^{\frac{1}{n-1}}=2$, so $\frac{1}{n-1}=\frac{1}{4}$, so $n=5$.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I will mark your answer as accepted as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

$$11 \cdot 16^{1/(n-1)} = 16^{n/(n-1)} - 10$$
$$11 \cdot 16^{1/(n-1)} = 16^{1+1/(n-1)} - 10$$

$$11 \cdot 16^{1/(n-1)} = 16\cdot16^{1/(n-1)} - 10$$

$$16\cdot 16^{1/(n-1)} - 11\cdot16^{1/(n-1)}=10$$

$$5\cdot 16^{1/(n-1)}=10$$

$$16^{1/(n-1)}=2=16^{1/4}$$
$$1/(n-1)=1/4$$
$$n=5$$